# How to convert fields into bags and tuples in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

**I have a dataset which has comma seperated values as:**

```
10,4,21,9,50,9,4,50    
50,78,47,7,4,7,4,50    
68,25,43,13,11,68,10,9
```

**I want to convert this into Bags and tuples as shown below:**

```
({(10),(4),(21),(9),(50)},{(9),(4),(50)})    
({(50),(78),(45),(7),(4)},{(7),(4),(50)})    
({(68),(25),(43),(13),(11)},{(68),(10),(9)})
```

**I have tried the below command but it does not show any data.**

```
grunt> dataset = load '/user/dataset' Using PigStorage(',') As (bag1:bag{t1:tuple(p1:int, p2:int, p3:int, p4:int, p5:int)}, bag2:bag{t2:tuple(p6:int, p7:int, p8:int)});

grunt> dump dataset;
```

**Below is the output of dump:**

```
2015-09-11 05:26:31,057 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 8 time(s).    
2015-09-11 05:26:31,057 [main] INFO      org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
2015-09-11 05:26:31,058 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-09-11 05:26:31,058 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2015-09-11 05:26:31,063 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-09-11 05:26:31,063 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1    
(,)    
(,)    
(,)    
(,)
```

Please help. How can I convert the dataset into bags and tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

I have used the below command:

```
grunt> dataset = load '/user/dataset' Using PigStorage(',') As (p1:int, p2:int, p3:int, p4:int, p5:int, p6:int, p7:int, p8:int);

grunt> dataset2 = Foreach dataset Generate TOBAG(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) as bag1, TOBAG(p6, p7, p8) as bag2;

grunt> dump dataset2;
```